# How to make dynamic webpages with JSON ID as URL- Google Charts, Fusiontables, Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-visualization, google-fusion-tables

How do I make dynamic webpages with JSON row ID as URL? I used Google Charts, Fusiontables, Jquery for a .click dynamic load so far.

So, this is a project where I create dynamic charts based on links I click. Here is a snippet of the code to give context:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function() { 

  var TQRG = "1k_R9v0tRK9Ut2HsKSWKviDd4ZDFGmNh550C-dCeK";
```

And then I set up the .click function:

```
$(".drawChart").click(function() {
    var trif_id = $(this).attr('id');
    drawVisualization(trif_id);
```

Of course having a draw visualization function associated with this:

```
 function drawVisualization(trif_id) {
    // get the data     
$.get("https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query", {sql:"SELECT * FROM "+TQRG+" WHERE TRIF_ID='"+trif_id+"'", key:apiKey}, function(response) {
var columns = response.columns;
var toxicReleased2010 = response.rows[0][2];
var toxicReleased2011 = response.rows[0][3];
```

-And then all the chart parameters.-

So Everything is drawn from google fusion charts, and the goal is to load charts according to unique ID. I have succeeded:

```
<a id="91745QMTCN720SO" class="drawChart" href="javascript:void(0);">Quemetco</a>
```

However, through the project, I have decided that it would be better if I could have dynamic URLS rather than click actions. Is there a way to seamlessly migrate this code to create URLS with the unique ID? for example mysite.html/91745QMTCN720SO

This is for a group project at school (toxic emission data presenting in a website), and my first stab at any coding at all. Please help me out, I just don't know where to start looking.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the ID's a URL parameter:

```
mysite.html?id=91745QMTCN720SO
```

and access them like this:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
var trif_id = getParameterByName('id');
```